# Frequency or count for PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I have a number of observations that is a count of a certain event occurring for a given user. For example

```
        login_count logout_count
user1            5            2
user2           20           10
user3           34            5
```

I would like to feed in these variables along along with a number of other ones to PCA, just wondering if I should work with counts directly (and scale the columns) or work with percentage (and scale the columns after) e.g

```
       login_count logout_count
user1         0.71         0.28
user2         0.66         0.33
user3         0.87         0.13
```

which one would be a better way of representing the data?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the information you want to extract from the data.

If the correlation `login=p*logout` then I would go with the first one.
The other one is a little bit weird since you should be doing a login 100% of the time (how wold you else know it's user1?) and a logout perhaps 28%. And also you have the dependency `1-login_procent_i=logout_procent_i` which will give you a perfect correlation before and after the preprocessing.